# Was there some type of animal that was kept locked up in the High Priest's house for sacrifice?

Tags: jesus

> Then took they him, and led him, and brought him into the high priest's house. And Peter followed afar off.
> (Lk. 22:54 KJV)

Was it common for animals to be brought to the High Priest's house for sacrifice? And maniated prisoners?

Comment: what part of the text makes your think that animals were brought the the high priest's house?

Comment: I didn't search any text. Perhaps I could do some research on the works of Philo of Alexandria and Josephus, but as of right now, I have nothing. I just suspected the way Jesus was taken.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is no. Animals were brought to the Temple area for sacrifice, not the high priest's house. [Norma Robertson](https://templemountlocation.com/animalsForSacrifice-Temple.html) explains that the number of animals was in the thousands and shows the location of their corals in this illustration:

[image]

Regarding prisoners, the whole trial was highly irregular. Moreover the Gospel of John reports that Jesus was not held at the house of the high priest himself but of his father-in-law, Annas.

> John 18:13-14
>
> They bound him and brought him first to Annas, who was the
> father-in-law of Caiaphas, the high priest that year. Caiaphas was the
> one who had advised the Jewish leaders that it would be good if one
> man died for the people.

Luke 3:2 speaks of "the high priesthood of Annas and Caiaphas" and Luke 22 refers to Jesus being tried by the "chief priests" among others. But from John's Gospel it is clear that it was the house of the former high priest, not the current one, where Jesus was held overnight. In either case, we should probably not envision a dungeon where prisoners were routinely held. This was a special case, where a prisoner was seized at night on the orders of the Temple authorities and brought to the (former) high priest's house for questioning.